# How to start with this ESC? Some simple questions

Tags: dc-motor

I'm building an autonomous boat for which I've been using a brushed DC motor. I now want to try my luck with a brushless DC motor. So I just ordered [this brushless motor](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000001623522.html) and I still have [this ESC](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32662395608.html) laying around (which I never used before).

My questions:

1. Can I use [this ESC](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32662395608.html) with [this motor](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000001623522.html)?
2. How do I know what kind of PWM values I need to send to the ESC? Is that the same for all ESCs? Or is that a trial and error thing?
3. Is it possible to use the ESC to reverse the direction of the motor? Or do I also need to use an H-bridge for that (just like I do with the brushed DC motor)?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: Trying to compare one aliexpress page with another aliexpress page and hoping to find some relevant technical data to might support your first question is pointless. Try searching for data sheets for the products and make the comparison yourself.

Comment: What @Andy aka says. I had some luck by contacting sellers on Aliexpress and they would send me a datasheet if they had one. Other ones simply said they don't have one and I looked somewhere else to buy from.

Comment: In the end I asked on the raspberry pi forum. So for future readers: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=251314&p=1533942  . In short: 1) Yes 2) 1000 µs (power off) to 2000 µs (full power) and 3) No (although I found ESCs which can).